# How to mock an external api in django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm trying to mock the "self.api.friends.get" method in VKAuth class:

```
import vk

class VKAuth(object):
    def __init__(self, access_token, user):
        self.session = vk.Session(access_token = access_token)
        self.api = vk.API(self.session)

    def follow(self):
        vk_friends = self.api.friends.get()
```

from the test module test_views.py:

```
from mock import patch
from ..auth_backends.vk_backend import VKAuth

class AddUsersToList(TestCase):
    @patch.object(VKAuth.api.friends, 'get')
    def test_auth_vk(self, mock_get):
         ... etc ...
```

And I get an error during testing:

```
AttributeError: <class 'accounts.auth_backends.vk_backend.VKAuth' doens't have the attribute 'api'
```

What am I doing wrong? How to get an access to this method in this class structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to mock a class itself, not it's instance. And the class doesn't have the `api` attribute, as it's created in your `__init__()`. Change your code to:

```
def test_auth_vk(self, mock_get):
    vk_auth = VKAuth(access_token, user)
    with mock.patch('vk_auth.api.friends') as friends_mock:
        friends_mock.get.return_value = None
        # Invoke the code that calls your api, passing the "vk_auth" variable as a backend.
        # ...
        friends_mock.mock.get.assert_called_with(your_arguments)
```

If you can't just pass an auth backend to your code, look up the place where it is instantiated and mock that place.

Comment: But what if I want to test it not directly passing the parameters to the class instance, but using django-rest-framework, which initializes this instance? In other words, I call " response = self.client.post(reverse('app-social-auth', {"access_token": "blablabla"}) " inside if the test method and I check the response.

Comment: You should look up the place where `social_auth` instantiates you backend and mock that instance. If you come up with the specific example, I'd try to help.

Comment: It is instantiated in accounts.views inside of the class AuthSocialView of method post as " auth_backends = { 'vk' : VKAuth, 'facebook' : FBAuth } "

Comment: And below we instantiate it: auth_backends[backend](access_token = s.data['access_token'], user=self.request.user)

Comment: What would it look like in my case? I mean, when instance is inside of the post method of the class view of the view module?

Comment: Then, I suppose, you should mock the upper-level object, or the transport-level things like `urllib`. What specific kind of functionality you're going to test?

Comment: What does it mean "the upper-level object"? I'm going to test if users are added to the friends list if they are already registered in the service. So I grab list of user friends from social network and then look them up in the database, and if they are already in the table - add them.

Comment: What is the upper-level object in my case? Neither accounts.views.VKAuth nor accounts.views.AuthSocialView look as the right object to mock.

Comment: I mean, you should mock either the higher-level code that returns the list of users fetched from Vk, or the HTTP transport functions that transmit the friends JSON or something. Sorry, but the question get broader and broader. The answer above resolves your particular code error (mocking the class instead the instance) you've come up with. If you want to ask a broader question, please make it a separate post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100599/discussion-between-paus-and-alex-morozov).

Comment: By the way the mock.patch('vk_auth.api.friends') call doesn't work, says: "ImportError: No module named vk_auth"